# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.ServerPlatformUtils.createServerPlatform(ServerPlatformUtils.java)

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, eclipselink, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

EclipseLink 2.6.1 (final) throws the following exception upon deploying a Java EE application on GlassFish Server 4.1. This had not been happening prior to upgrading from 2.6.0.

```
Warning:   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.ServerPlatformUtils.createServerPlatform(ServerPlatformUtils.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.init(SessionManager.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.<clinit>(SessionManager.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.addSessionToGlobalSessionManager(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:907)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.initSession(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2676)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:395)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Although it is a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, the `LOG` level is `Warning`.

[`org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager#init()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.1-RC1/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/factories/SessionManager.java#SessionManager.init%28%29) is defined as follows (though grepcode shows RC1).

```
74     private static void init() {
75         String platformClass = ServerPlatformUtils.detectServerPlatform(null);
76         try {
77             detectedPlatform = ServerPlatformUtils.createServerPlatform(null, platformClass, SessionManager.class.getClassLoader());
78         } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
79             //some platforms may not be handling 'null' session well,
80             //so be defensive here and only log throwable here
81             detectedPlatform = null;
82             LOG.logThrowable(SessionLog.WARNING, AbstractSessionLog.CONNECTION, npe);
83         }
84         supportPartitions = detectedPlatform != null && detectedPlatform.usesPartitions();
85         if (supportPartitions) {
86             managers = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, SessionManager>(4, 0.9f, 1);
87             SessionManager sm = initializeManager();
88             manager = sm;
89             managers.put(sm.context, sm);
90         } else {
91             manager = initializeManager();
92         }
93     }
```

Where [`createServerPlatform(DatabaseSession session, String platformClass, ClassLoader loader)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.1-RC1/org/eclipse/persistence/platform/server/ServerPlatformUtils.java#ServerPlatformUtils.createServerPlatform%28org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatabaseSession%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.ClassLoader%29) throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, if `platformClass` is `null`.

```
97     public static ServerPlatform createServerPlatform(DatabaseSession session, String platformClass, ClassLoader loader) {
98         if (platformClass == null) {
99             throw new NullPointerException();
100        }

           //...
       }
```

It appears to be normal according to the code. Is it?

Comment: How are you deploying Eclipselink to Glassfish?

Comment: As usual using an IDE, NetBeans in this case which possesses a deployer known as Apache Ant (I do not use Apache Maven) which performs the task of deploying applications.

Comment: You know that Glassfish allready implements a different version of eclipselink (I think 2.5.2)? Did you change the glassfish implementation to work with 2.6.1? If you add the jar to a war you are deploying on glassfish, I guess there can be version conflicts.

Comment: There is no version conflict. The default version supplied by GlassFish is replaced by a newer version (2.6.1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although that exception appears to be normal, it is no longer reproducible in EclipseLink 2.6.2 released on December 22, 2015.

So, if you happened to worry about that exception, consider upgrading EclipseLink to that version (**2.6.2**).