# How to configure properly the db in a javaee application?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I setted a connection pool and a JDBC resource on the Glassfish's admin UI. Ping works. However I got this exception when i deploy my ear to the Glassfish webserver.

```
Warning:   java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.ServerPlatformUtils.createServerPlatform(ServerPlatformUtils.java:99)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.init(SessionManager.java:77)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.<clinit>(SessionManager.java:71)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.removeSessionFromGlobalSessionManager(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:558)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.undeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2982)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.close(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:268)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.close(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:288)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.closeEMFs(JPADeployer.java:414)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:405)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.unload(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1067)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.undeploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1099)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.UndeployCommand.execute(UndeployCommand.java:412)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My persistence.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="appPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/FoosballDB</jta-data-source>
    <class>hu.unideb.entity.User</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Please help me out guys, I don't why it's not working and have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: I'm using Netbeans IDE. Do you think still it is caused by the IDE in this case?

Comment: there are similar fixed problems on thoses question  in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296319/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-org-eclipse-persistence-platform-server-server and in :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142789/nullpointer-in-log-during-first-connection-to-database

Comment: `jdbc/FoosballDB` is defined?

Comment: yes it's defined as a JDBC resource on the glassfish server.